# Bash command value assignment

Tags: bash, shell

Can anyone please explain what the following bash command does?

```
CMD_PATH=${0%/*}
```

What is the value assigned to the CMD_PATH variable?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows the first directory on the working running process. If it is in a script, it shows its name.

From [What exactly does "echo $0" return](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/what-exactly-does-echo-%240-return-782908/):

> $0 is the name of the running process. If you use it inside a shell,
>   then it will return the name of the shell. If you use it inside a
>   script, it will be the name of the script.

Let's explain it:

```
$ echo $0
/bin/bash
```

is the same as

```
$ echo ${0}
/bin/bash
```

Then a bash substitution is done: get text up to last slash:

```sh
$ echo ${0%/*}
/bin
```

This substitution can be understood with this example:

```
$ a="hello my name is me"
$ echo ${a% *}
hello my name is
```

Comment: Sure, did not check properly. See my updated answer, @anubhava

Answer (score 4):

It strips anything beyond last occurence of slash character from `$0` variable, which is ([in most cases](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028), sometimes depending on how the script is run) the folder the script is currently executed from.

Answer (score 1):

Returns the name of the directory from which the currently running script has been started.

To test it:

- create directory `/tmp/test`:

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/test
  ```
- create file 't.sh` with such content:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  echo $0
  echo ${0%/*}
  ```
- give `t.sh` execution permission:

  ```
  chmod +x /tmp/test/t.sh
  ```
- execute it and you will see:

  ```
  /tmp/test/s.sh
  /tmp/test
  ```